# How do I renew an expired domain with Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace

I let my domain expire on Google Apps. It now says that I have to contact customer service in order to renew.

Does anyone know how to renew a domain (still under the grace period) for Google Apps.

Comment: Try looking in the domain settings in the google apps control panel: http://google.com/a

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Apps for domains help center:

> To renew your registration of this domain:
>
> Visit the URL http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/renew-domain/primary-domain-name, where primary-domain-name is the expired domain name.
> Log in with the Google Checkout account that you previously used to register the domain.

See the full help doc here: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174725#175550

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your billing info and click on auto renew within 2 business days it will be renewed, if you exceed your trial period you will be charged $58 and will have to buy through GoDaddy.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to see if you will be able to renew the domain name using Dodaddy account directly

Comment: The domain is still within the _grace period_, so it will not be available for registration via another registrar.